# Binary search tree search operation

Tags: search, data-structures, binary-search-tree

> I would like to know what must be true about a binary search tree to efficiently search it.

Comment: it must be balanced, ie the left and right nodes have roughly the same number of children

Answer (score 1):

In order to efficiently search a binary search tree, the tree must be *balanced*. That is, the left and right subtrees of each node have approximately the same number of children. When a binary search tree is perfectly balanced, searching it is an O(log n) operation. A degenerate tree, on the other hand, has all of the nodes on the right (or left) subtree. Searching that is like searching a linked list: O(n).

See the Wikipedia article, [Binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The tree needs to be self-balancing, which means that the height of the tree is minimized while keeping the binary search tree properties. Search for AVL tree or self-balancing tree for more info. Binary search performed on an AVL tree results in an `O(logn)` runtime, whereas binary search on a normal BST results in an `O(n)` runtime.